# Is that possible that typescript inference to direct inference value and drop the key

Tags: typescript, class, types, inference

```
class A {
  state: B
}
class B {
  something: C
}
class C {
  a: string;
  b: boolean;
}

type MagicType = ...

const c: MagicType<A>

c.state.a = "123"
c.state.b = true;
```

As the example mention that, without changing the class structure is that possible to have magic type to achieve this?

Ignore the `something` key but just export `class c` property

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is mapped types for that.

```
class Foo{
  constructor(public bar:string,public baz:number){}
}



type State<T> = {
  "state": { [P in keyof T]: T[P] };
};

var fooState: State<Foo> = {
  state : new Foo("bar",1)
}

console.log(fooState.state.bar);
```

Playground [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=15&ssc=33&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD28DeAoa1jwHYQC4CcBXYXefACgAdCAjEAS2GhrHwC4996sBzAGmp1GzMAC82WQgFsaAU3wBKJAF8UqlBtwBPSrOgBlXGFyyAPABUAfNAC80VOgBEeY7Mdt70ANoAFaN2gAa1kteAAzaHMAXQ9zXyjoZQBuNRSUADdWaDDEQ1cPPJNTBHhrOwdoFxNoDyxZAHc4RHJHFnxHPgBGBTUNTBx4EFkAOhB4HnIc+EKRqpG2hSSgA)

See also [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types)